# Distance from one point to a sphere not on the same plane

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry, spheres

I am trying to measure the distance that a point would be over a sphere. To explain further:

Point $A$ is $(-580,1130,2500)$. Point $B$ is $(-1500,3600,7570)$. However, Point $A$ creates a sphere with a radius of $4500$ at the top. The sphere is most likely extending to Point $B$ at some length.

I am trying to find if the top of Point $B$ is outside of the sphere that Point $A$ creates. If so, how much outside of the sphere is it.

Comment: Calculate the distance between $A$ and $B$ using the distance formula, and subtract from that, the radius $R= 4500$.  The result is the distance between point $B$ and the surface of the sphere centered at $A$.

Comment: @GeometryLover would that distance be the vertical distance from the surface of the sphere at Center A to the top of B? I'm having a bit of a hard time visualizing this

Comment: The distance calculation I described would give you the radial distance above the surface of the sphere.  I assumed this is what you meant by 'over the sphere' in the first line of the question.  If you meant the distance along the $z$-axis then the calculation is different.

Comment: @GeometryLover then I was mistaken in my original wording. I meant to ask about the distance along the z-axis

Comment: Equation of sphere centered at $A$ is $(x + 580)^2 + (y - 1130)^2 + (z - 2500)^2 = (4500)^2$.  Substitute $x = -1500, y =  3600 $ in the above equation, and solve for $z, z \gt 2500$.  Then the distance you're looking for is $7570 - z$.